# hook in the entity framework generated proxy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, proxy

Currently I'm building an application that supports localization of the database content. So some entities have 2 entities.

```
- Entity
- EntityTranslation
```

The entity has the same fields, but only the values for the default language. The translation table supports the other languages. Whenever I want to retrieve a translated result I have to do a where query on the translation entity. This makes the code less readable then desired.

At first I was thinking to hook something in my repo's. So, when the entity is derived from localizedEntity I would check the users language and if that is not the default I would fetch the translation entity from the table and copy them over the entity. (simple explenation, in practice a lot more work.)

Though, when an entity is accessed via the navigation property this would not work. This is handled by entity framework via the generated proxy. So my question is, can I somehow hook into this generated proxy and add custom logic to it? I tried to find documentation that would indicate a starting point to hook in this process, but thusfar I was not succesful. I was hoping someone already did something like this.

Comment: Can you give an example of the query you want to build?

Comment: Have you looked into inheriting ObjectContext and seeing whats available such as ObjectContext.CreateProxyTypes ? Also have a read of this... http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/369845/Localization-with-Entity-Framework

Comment: Just a normal where query. Probably with some reflection and confentions to get the right objects.

Comment: Paul, this does a bit what I want, though I would like to have it also available via the proxy if possible. This saves a lot of code... But I'm unsure if this would be possible at all.